# Не удается десериализировать группу JSON-объектов

Tags: c#, .net, json

Данные загружаю из файла:

```
{
  "Date": "22.05.2018 20:17:43",
  "Windows account": "DNAPC\\Администратор",
  "title":  [
    "System.Web.Razor.resources.dll",
    "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.resources.dll"
   ]
}
{
  "Date": "22.05.2018 20:38:52",
  "Windows account": "DNAPC\\Администратор",
  "title": [
    "System.Web.Helpers.resources.dll",
    "System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll",
    "System.Web.Optimization.resources.dll",
    "System.Web.Razor.resources.dll",
    "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.resources.dll"
  ]
}
```

Models:

```
class JsonRecord
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Date")]
        public string date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Windows account")]
        public string windowsAccount = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
        public string[] title { set; get; } 
    }
```

Основной код:

```
string jsonString;
            using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader("History deleted files/history.json", System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {

                jsonString = sw.ReadToEnd();
                
            }
            var jR = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonRecord>>(jsonString); // <= ERROR
            foreach(var item in jR)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.date);
            }
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Wpf_Directory_Cleaner.Resources.JsonRecord]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."
```

Уже пробовал даже IEnumerable - ошибка та же.
Если делать так:

```
var jR = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRecord>(jsonString);
```

Здесь один объект, все работает, но только с одним объектом JSON. A у меня группа, которая подгружается из файла.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить Array на List

Comment: **1.** Вы не понимаете что такое JSON. Научитесь читать его так, будто это обычный текст. Поймите какие типы используются (string, list, dictionary или что то еще). **2.** У вас неверное понимание тега ` [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Date")]` - им вы задаете имя "помеченного" объекта в json. К примеру, есть у вас такой JSON `{"Value": "22.05.2018"}`, но в классе вы хотите это назвать как Data (что приведет к ошибке, ибо такого значения нету в JSON, вы помечаете его с помощью ` [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Date")]` и все встает на свои места. **3.** У вас невалидный JSON. Он не десериализуется

Comment: Да, на шарпе з JSON первый раз работаю, перекодил за вашими рекомендациями, есть изменения на виводе... и все это из-за неверного опреления атрибута

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формируетй файл следующим образом:

```
[{
      "Date": "22.05.2018 20:17:43",
      "Windows account": "DNAPC\\Администратор",
      "title":  [
        "System.Web.Razor.resources.dll",
        "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.resources.dll"
       ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "22.05.2018 20:38:52",
      "Windows account": "DNAPC\\Администратор",
      "title": [
        "System.Web.Helpers.resources.dll",
        "System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll",
        "System.Web.Optimization.resources.dll",
        "System.Web.Razor.resources.dll",
        "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.resources.dll"
      ]
    }]
```

И используйте

```
var jR = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonRecord>>(str);
```

Десериализовать можно либо объект, либо массив, а у вас в файле два объекта.

Comment: Зделал, та самая ошибка. Даже  если так зделаю - не вариант, файл обновляеться

Comment: 1. У меня этот вариант работает. 2. Если файл обновляется, то либо вы програмно подгоняете под нужный формат, либо не используете десериализацию